# Popover Boostrap 3 - Não aparece

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, popover

Estou com o seguinte **código HTML:**

```
<button class="thumb-hearth pop" data-toggle="popover" title="Likes" data-placement="top" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Teste">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
</button>
```

Com o seguinte **JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.pop').popover().click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.pop').popover('hide');
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

Porém, não apresenta nenhum resultado do meu **popOver na ação de click (o DOM chega a receber uma alteração)**, mas o popover não aparece, e quando consulto o console, vejo o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at a.MixItUp._processClick (mp-jquery.mixitup.min.js:14)
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (mp-jquery.mixitup.min.js:14)
    at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (mp-jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLLIElement.r.handle (mp-jquery.min.js:3)
```

**Não faço ideia de onde pode estar o erro. O que poderia fazer para corrigir?**

Comment: Consegui remover o erro, entretanto, o popover não aparece.

Comment: Importou o bootstrap.min.js ?

Comment: Sim! @VME, fiz a importação

Answer (score 2):

A [documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) informa que esse mecanismo (`popover`) não é automático. Vc precisa instanciar / inicializar (vide *Opt-in functionality*).

No *snippet* abaixo você vai ver `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();` no *JavaScript*, e é isso que está disparando a instância.

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  $('.pop').popover().click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.pop').popover('hide');
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
<br><br>
<button class="thumb-hearth pop" data-toggle="popover" title="Likes" data-placement="top" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Teste">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Minha estrutura está exatamente igual a essa, entretanto o popover não aparece e apresenta o mesmo erro.

Comment: Se vc se refere a `Cannot read property`, entenda: Como vc pode ver no _snippet_, se sua configuração estiver igual a da resposta não tem como aparecer esse erro. Se ele funciona aqui, tb funciona no seu ambiente. Provavelmente esse erro vem de outro _script_ ou função que vc está carregando.

Comment: Estou usando o jqueryMixitUp, será que pode existir um conflito?

Comment: Vc vai ter que remover o _jqueryMixitUp_ e testar.

Comment: Estou injetando tudo dentro de uma li, usando o append. Veja como está: http://prnt.sc/e92qoa ... Quando eu clico no botão, ele cria uma alteração no DOM em ul e li (coloca inline). Mas não sei pq não aparece o popover.